# AssetTranslationException: During translation of SCSS code MVC

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sass

After I deploy my MVC Application on server i got this error , and this is first time that my project do this during deployment . My Application locally is working and in previous time i deployed and it was working also but i deployed again after updates to show this error , also this error appears for any old working version before updates

[image: Error]

Comment: Not clearly visible